# Simple Algorithm complexity

Tags: java, algorithm, complexity-theory, code-complexity

I have an algorithm and I need help finding the complexity of it (tightest possible upper bound)

```
for(int i = 0; i < n/2; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < n/4; j++)
        for(int k = 0; k < n; k++)
            x++;
```

My analysis is that if n would not be divided in each for loop, it would be `O(n^3)`. This complexity still holds true, since each "for loop" will reduce each operation to a `O(log n)` complexity since it divides n every time the loop executes, making it smaller and smaller (smaller than `O(n)` at least).

I would say that the answer is between `O(log n)` and `O(n^3)`. Could you help me getting the tightest possible bound?

Comment: `n` is never modified => complexity `Θ(n * (n/4) * (n/2)) = Θ(n³)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

start with inner loop :

```
for(int k = 0; k < n; k++)
    x++;
```

is obviously O(n).

now one layer above that :

```
for(int j = 0; j < n/4; j++)
```

is O(n) because it takes **n/4** for j to reach the **n** and we know that O(n/4) = O(n)

and like this for outer loop is O(n).so the complexity is `O(n^3)` **because you have three nested loop each with O(n) and non of them have effect on each other.**

Comment: Ok! So the tightest bound possible for this algorithm is indeed O(n^3) ?

Answer (score 3):

Assume each step takes time C.
For k-loop, time taken is C*n.
For j-loop, time taken to complete iteration is (C*n)*n/4=C*(n^2)/4
For i-loop, time taken to complete iteration is (C*(n^2)/4)*n/2=C*(n^3)/8

So Total time taken=(C/8)*(n^3)

As C/8 is a constant it can be ignored when considering Big-O Notation.
Thus, Time Complexity=O(n^3).

Comment: my answer in words is urs

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i = 0; i < n/2; i++)    --> n/2
    for(int j = 0; j < n/4; j++)  --> n/4
        for(int k = 0; k < n; k++)  --> n
            x++;
```

Hence total complexity is `O((n^3)/8)` which is `O(n^3)`

Comment: How do you get from O(n^3/8) to O(n^3)?

Comment: 8 is a constant , and can be ignored